# VSTO add-in not loading with /// in URI to manifest, however it loads with \\\

Tags: vsto, uri

I have been successfully using a Manifest string of:

```
file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\PathTo\MyAddin.vsto|vstolocal
```

in the registry. So it looks like this:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\..\Microsoft\Office\Word\Addins\MyAddin\@Manifest=file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\PathTo\MyAddin.vsto|vstolocal
```

It loads fine like this for me, and thousands of other people. Well, except on ONE machine in our shop - it won't load for him unless I remove the `file:///` or reverse the whacks so they are `file:\\\`.

I have same .Net Framework 4.5.1 and VSTO Runtime 10.0.50903 as the person experiencing the issue. How could this be happening? Is there a correct URI format? Following [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsod/archive/2011/06/14/vsto-4-0-sp1-will-cause-a-vsto-addin-to-not-find-its-config-file.aspx) article it says to use `///` (which I also believe to be proper for URI). Following [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2006/12/06/file-uris-in-windows.aspx) article it also says `///` is correct

Answer (score 1):

I have been developing VSTO add-ins for a long time and I always prefer to use `Manifest` without `file///` or `file\\\` prefix.

Simply use this

> `C:\Program Files (x86)\PathTo\MyAddin.vsto|vstolocal`

OR

Use this in case you want to load Config file.
Covert the face of few slashes

> file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\PathTo\MyAddin.vsto|vstolocal

To

> file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/PathTo/MyAddin.vsto|vstolocal

Comment: I wish I can agree with you but I need to load app.config and there is a bug when you don't use full URI: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsod/archive/2011/06/14/vsto-4-0-sp1-will-cause-a-vsto-addin-to-not-find-its-config-file.aspx

Comment: @jJack I have edited my answer, well you can also try to load config file on demand. While developing, I use file/// but during deployment, I remove this. Config is loaded on demand and I never get deployment failure.

Comment: So are you saying if I use all / slashes instead of \ slashes in the path, I will NOT run into issues loading a config file (as I mentioned in the link above)? I'm not sure what you mean by 'on demand'. However the issues is that we have third party software which loads our config, so that might not be an option.

Comment: @jJack by 'on demand' means loading config file by supplying path to exe or dll. For third party, I can't say that it will accept it or not. While debugging, you may have noticed the registry entries, it has all the / slashes and it loads the config file also.